# Display и DisplayName не работают для Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

У меня простой веб АПИ проект. Все на .NET Core 3.1. Для маппинга json на view модели использую newtonsoft json. Я покажу, как я это в `Startup.cs` подключаю:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

и пакет `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.

И еще у меня вот такая view модель:

```
public class AdvertiserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty inner id!!!!!!")]
    [JsonProperty("inner_id")]
    [DisplayName("inner_id")]
    public int ? InnerId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty name!!!!!")]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [DisplayName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

И вот такой контроллер:

```
[Route("/api/advertisers/create")]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<AdvertiserViewModel>> Create([FromBody] AdvertiserViewModel viewModel)
{     
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var advertiser = new Advertiser
    {
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        AdvertiserRed2Id = viewModel.InnerId.Value
    };

    await _dbContext.Advertisers.AddAsync(advertiser);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

И вот такой реквест:

```
{
    "name": "hello!!!",
    "inner_id": null
}
```

Получаю в качестве респонса

```
{
  "InnerId": [
    "Empty inner id!!!!!!"
  ]
}
```

Но это же не логично! Мой клиент ничего не знает о `InnerId`. Он знает лишь о `inner_id`.

Я нашел вот такой код фильтра, чтоб исправить это:

```
public class DisplayNameValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
        {
            var modelType = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters
                .FirstOrDefault(p =>
                    p.BindingInfo.BindingSource.Id.Equals("Body", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                    p.BindingInfo.BindingSource.Id.Equals("Custom", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    )
                ?.ParameterType; //Get model type  

            var expandoObj = new ExpandoObject();
            var expandoObjCollection =
                (ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>)
                expandoObj; //Cannot convert IEnumrable to ExpandoObject  

            var dictionary = context.ModelState.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
                .Where(v => v.Value.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)
                .ToDictionary(
                    k =>
                    {
                        if (modelType != null)
                        {
                            var property = modelType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
                                p.Name.Equals(k.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                            if (property != null)
                            {
                                //Try to get the attribute  
                                var displayName = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
                                    .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()?.DisplayName;
                                return displayName ?? property.Name;
                            }
                        }

                        return k.Key; //Nothing found, return original vaidation key  
                    },
                    v => v.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList() as Object); //Box String collection  
            foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
            {
                expandoObjCollection.Add(keyValuePair);
            }

            dynamic eoDynamic = expandoObj;
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(eoDynamic);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Использование этого чуда:

```
[DisplayNameValidationFilter]
MyControllerClass : ControllerBase {...}
```

Но ведь это же просто костыль, верно? Я вынужден таскать это из солюшена в солюшен. Неужели нет какого-то способа из коробки? 
Я пробовал Display, DisplayName, JsonPropertyName (это вроде уже из стандартного пакета Json Text). Ничего не работает. Я не могу понять, почему это является проблемой? Кто-нибудь, подскажите пожалуйста стандартный способ это сделать!

#### Обновление

попробовал установить глобально стратегию для сериализации json

```
services.AddControllers(
    ).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
   // options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(DefaultContractResolver));
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()));
});
```

Нет эффекта(

Comment: Ответ здесь. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604600/7542937 позже приведу рабочий код

Answer (score 1):

Итак, кажется я это решил! Пользователь @A K♦ был прав, надо задать стратегию сериализации. И тут у нас всплывают следующие варианты:

- Использовать старый добрый NetonsoftJson;
- Использовать новый Text.Json (с .NET Core 3.0 появился)

В моем случае последний вариант не работает, так как не поддерживает нативную реализацию `snake_case`. В интернете с пол клика гуглится стат о том, как сделать свою. [Вот](https://medium.com/@hannan.sultan1/adding-custom-naming-convention-to-the-new-system-text-json-in-net-core-c52f63f28a4f). Данная реализация ругалась у меня на некоторые варианты JSON. Изучать я это не стал и решил использовать старый добрый проверенный ньютонсофт.

Итак, вот рабочая конфигурация

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true,
            ProcessExtensionDataNames = true
        }                        
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону указания стратегии наименования полей, что-то типа:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()));
});
```

И вообще перестаньте указывать JsonProperty на свойствах (как минимум - на совпадающих с политикой).

Этих стратегий в json.net множество, подробнее см. в [документации](https://www.newtonsoft.com/Json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization.htm).

Примеры на en so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34070459/5752652

---

Судя по всему вам нужна стратегия SnakeCase

```
var model = new AdvertiserViewModel { InnerId = 123, Name = "something"};

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver 
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()      
    },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, serializerSettings);
json.Dump();
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdvertiserViewModel>(json, serializerSettings);
deserialized.Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так, так, так ... щас проверю. Спасибо!

Comment: Попробовал предложенный вариант, убрал JsonProperty, пробовал DefaultNamingStrategy - ничего не помогает. Все тот же респонс.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak У меня нет под рукой машины с core 3.x но судя по синтетическому примеру в Linqpad вам нужна SnakeCaseNamingStrategy - см. пример в обновлении ответа.

Comment: Можете обновление глянуть? Может как то не так настраиваю эту стратегию?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak На вид выглядит правильно, но я третий core только на домашней машине гонял простые проекты, под рукой нету. Если будет возможность -- постараюсь сегодня вечером глянуть или завтра. Пока вот только могу помочь только таким указанием пути: вы указываете подходящую стратегию, json.net её использует при сериализации и десериализации. Пока попробуйте сами подебажить - посмотреть какие когда данные приходят, как уходит на десериализацию. Ну и погуглить по тем ключевикам, что я подкинул.

Comment: Я очень благодарен за помощь! Очень хотелось бы избавиться от того велосипеда, который я прикрепил к вопросу (я про аннотацию для показа ключей из пришедшего json при выводе сообщений валидации)